# how to convert byte array into image further please see question

Tags: arrays, byte, fingerprint, digital, persona

I need your help 
i am making an application to register visitors with their fingerprint. The application is saving fingerprint in a  database and doing verification properly , but I want to show the fingerprints on my web page. Thet byte array is not coming back into image like thumb image. I want that byte array in image.
thumb is going in database in this format:

øMÈ*ãs\ÀA7  «q°ÑU’ñƒ/~ùT}8¿^‡Ð÷»{…ymÐ­m«öÐ€iÿF’R"Ä\Ë’~ÂHë"Ú{l–²jý6†7´n™}1Q GDñ÷pü·|L“èY·«¡¼îo;Ð`ú—Ìz›ô×RD‚e‰³˜ËðÂmF7ËØ¦á\Ì–OÁ"8-§,;åu–Éy¶–'¹»)ºÆÒD» Þå&ã ôf…ëƒÃ\‰¤¡eö2£Ê¶TGÓbÂ.[YãG×ž:¬ÅŠ+Mkfãv„ú|v+da8>¡Øáµü‘`V^€·~‰hÌsH†ÜAÈ;‰è÷ßšÆ¶¢MVBdó6¿T)š‚©šÞY{¢‘Z   Ü~Ÿþ>=ª'Ð»g¡#uRfx°­Y”¥ï¬Â½+4á4DF°ƒÁëoøZÈ*ãs\ÀA7 «qpÛU’×Îsü5`B'B…ñ@¡°_ßàsº
4«9lê#7ŽãÿuÅM‹’,‰j1…lûÞôÏþ ‡áã”j¡;ùôOli"ÆÁ«s€µ%×]{ë÷qHlrÇ,„Ž’æ„îÎß|{â{ÆŸuƒ'JGáŒ‘ÀÆâŠä®¥H¶Mzœl/œ¹±A7{Uf4®D‹ÃÌ6Ú2l,%ã%wK0eÎ£û(+¨«”#UX5³YÎ³©mÑâŒL³îEÒ
ÔéWäy'°%æ£‚ymí7_!Ç†§õµT8jA+v!>g„f·¼ú÷ÆE›àÖfáPàþÖ_yE²ö$Éžþ¸[é»y_sÊCâë%¿rh&ù:×ÇÕÄNþnGwÿq@á    JNÄG)!!zÝofÙQo²øŠ–Ù
Ÿnï¶LoøÈ*ãs\ÀA7 «q°ÒU’q5Xƒ<YÚd%…ô0vvË²liªØ|:@Ï=\ìr*?lz™‹ƒ=!´ÄîDžÞí›ûþ‚SlÈL²`Ù­Ðª¥E"ßx¡Ù¥ Î‡ƒëX&ñšB©//-Òú!÷‰?aœwäáæ–$½nG©WbÓ-µÐüŒûe­n)™¡a¤ÛF—«êþõ£JfH¿Å—ÓË\g ]A„¹eâóT²^…6pê8Ñ6…†õŽ¢…ýUJ)''Kx©Âˆù©ÜñÂìÖ4s„4¦sÒ«PR,“žÁc->$|SRH•€ã+

> ¡sæ+TY´ëà*y þ’óâ\¬2Ö¯=Ž3âgí)qjýcÎ‘qâŒiºI²ÁÛÄt:ÉC»#¡^ÚzmGäü‚Èzæ Ÿ+uRFûõ›»Á·øÚ3ÓªÅc¾ò+-Œw_úAÐ‡Dé©O9GTg†¸b÷ßloèbÈ*ãs\ÀA7  «qð×U’[Õà”v;’ú  6“í¡|Ñ(·™Åƒ†Äê¤ÙÁ+:u&:&Md†Í‰t|‡ÿÇ¤A¤Í™u2Ãö_µ®´³ªìbu7ÖÄd<ñÄ |Ðt+ÐÂÊ¼ˆÉ:ÒÜð÷óÊ‹WLªIBaÄ€>-Å¦‡;„—¾{Ðš8‘€³Þ¤¯}çõý#­ôx9]ç\Í2$¾œõI°;ÿ6(Ö9  xÜ€æêJTÅN½èB¾x‰6¼ÌÃ¡×œÝ”    °ÔI¹öŸÑë`L!É,ZÎyÕ?=XLë(3?UK6˜#â«o±{€ò¹õç    ÒÒ—„Àd`%Ó¸f­#hf>žÐ9à3ƒ>æ´Úéû„µëeBËpu?90½|EÉíýzdF3R^p'¼Û)ŒéÜ¼,Ç[åWZñ
>   ÒFµàö¸™~×YpoÕÑÌÐÖÚÙÕØàáàààâÛÚÝÝßâãããêåçêçèéçèìîêçéîììñõôòïïñôòò÷ûûúîõüûõõøûùõõñôøñïóøùöý÷õõöýþüøóì÷óóûýñíîðëÕÈÈÏÔàáèòõõöùþûåÔÈ¿µ³•‘ »ò÷ûýüýõùþþþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿùþþþ÷õóíÝÛÖØàãêìð÷þ

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please always look at the preview of your post before posting. Your post has severe formatting problems. Please [edit] your post to fix these issues

Comment: What you use for verification, is not the image of the finger; it is the fingerprint template. If you want to later retrieve and display the image, you must save it, too.